# How to add an Array List inside another Array List in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have a data structure of the following form:

```
HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>> map = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>>();
```

// I am trying to add a new list inside the map's value if the value is already present in the hash.

```
while(//some condition){
  if(!map.containsKey(//some value)){
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    map.put(//some value, list);
    ArrayList<Integer> currentList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    currentList.add(1); currentList.add(2);
    map.get(//some value).set(map.get(//some value).size(), currentList);
  }
  else{
    ArrayList<Integer> currentList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    currentList.add(1); currentList.add(2);
    map.get(//some value).set(map.get(//some value).size(), currentList);
  }
}
```

> But this throws up an error saying IndexOutOfBoundsException at Index:
>   0 and Size: 0

Comment: What line is the exception?

Comment: To add something to an arraylist, you use the add() method. Not the set() method. set() replaces an element by something else. But your list has no element. Read the javadoc.

Comment: Btw: bad idea to replace code with "some value", since one of them is the culprit here. Most likely this `map.get(//some value).set(map.get(//some value).size(), currentList)`, because using `size()` is obviously a **very bad** idea for adding a new item (see JB Nizets comment above).

Comment: Thanks a lot @JBNizet, it explains clearly why I can't do this.

Comment: Thanks @Tom for the suggestion.